# What is the different between Stuff functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any difference between these two Stuff statements? I am not proper understanding, because first one is stuffed with '**' but in second it concatenates the column values.

1. `select stuff(Name,2,3,'**')`
2. `select stuff(','+Name from tablename for xml path(' ') ),1,1,' ')`

Please make me clear in simple way.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That functionality is product specific.)

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: Second one concatenates because of `xml path(' ')` not because of `STUFF`

Comment: Yes, Exactly. Thank to all for their valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stuff Function:**

The STUFF function inserts a string into another string. It deletes a specified length of characters in the first string at the start position and then inserts the second string into the first string at the start position.

**Example:**

```
select stuff('Stack overflow',1,5,'Knowledge')

--output--

Knowledge overflow
```

**Stuff For Xml Path:**

Stuff for xml path is used for concatenate multiple records and shows in a single record based on  your particular unique record

Example:

```
declare @t table( Id int, Name varchar(10))

insert into @t
select 1,'a' union all
select 1,'b' union all
select 2,'c' union all
select 2,'d' 

select ID,
stuff((    select ','+ [Name] from @t where Id = t.Id for XML path('')),1,1,'') as concat_records 
from (select distinct ID from @t )t

ID  concat_records
1   a,b
2   c,d
```

For better understaning the Stuff [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx](http://Msdn)

Note: Sorry for my English .Hope you understand what i want to explain.

Answer (score 0):

```html
select stuff('Name',2,3,'**')    -- Start From 2nd Character and Replace 3 character with '**'

select stuff(SELECT DISTINCT ', ' +  Name 
                            -- Add a comma (,) before each value
 from tablename  FOR XML PATH('') -- Select it as XML
                        ), 1, 1, '' )
                        -- This is done to remove the first character
```